# background image doesn't show up in div tag

Tags: html, css

I try to put a background image in a div tag with class, and I did give it the width and height also the direction to the image is correct, but somehow the image didn't show up. Can someone help me please, thank you!

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  color: #777;
  line-height: 1.8;
}


/* Create a Parallax Effect */

.bgimg-1,
.bgimg-2,
.bgimg-3 {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* First image (Logo. Full height) */

.bgimg-1 {
  background-image: url('../images/home.jpeg');
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">
<style>
  .bgimg-1 {
    background: url('../images/home.jpeg');
    min-height: 100%;
  }
</style>

<body>

  <!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->
  <div class="w3-top">
    <div class="w3-bar" id="myNavbar">
      <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-black w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#home" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">HOME</a>
      <a href="#about" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#portfolio" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> PORTFOLIO</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> CONTACT</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-right w3-hover-red">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Navbar on small screens -->
    <div id="navDemo" class="w3-bar-block w3-white w3-hide w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium">
      <a href="#about" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="toggleFunction()">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#portfolio" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="toggleFunction()">PORTFOLIO</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="toggleFunction()">CONTACT</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">SEARCH</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- First Parallax Image with Logo Text -->
  <div class="bgimg-1 w3-display-container w3-opacity-min" id="home">
    <div class="w3-display-middle" style="white-space:nowrap;">
      <span class="w3-center w3-padding-large w3-black w3-xlarge w3-wide w3-animate-opacity">MY <span class="w3-hide-small">WEBSITE</span> LOGO</span>

    </div>
  </div>
```

p.s. It will work if I use internal css, but I want to see if there's a way can reach the same goal with external css. Thanks for your help and patience, really appreciate it.

Comment: Avoid `../` relative paths in your CSS. Use domain-relative, eg. if your image is at `https://example.com/images/home.jpeg` then you'd use `/images/home.jpeg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should add *Relative path* for you background image  `background-image: url('realtive path url');` *URL*

```css
body,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

body,
html {
  height: 100%;
  color: #777;
  line-height: 1.8;
}


/* Create a Parallax Effect */

.bgimg-1,
.bgimg-2,
.bgimg-3 {
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}


/* First image (Logo. Full height) */

.bgimg-1 {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/10/800/800');
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 300px;
  width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/styles.css">

<body>

  <!-- Navbar (sit on top) -->
  <div class="w3-top">
    <div class="w3-bar" id="myNavbar">
      <a class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hover-black w3-hide-medium w3-hide-large w3-right" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="toggleFunction()" title="Toggle Navigation Menu">
        <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
      </a>
      <a href="#home" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">HOME</a>
      <a href="#about" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#portfolio" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small"><i class="fa fa-th"></i> PORTFOLIO</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small"><i class="fa fa-envelope"></i> CONTACT</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button w3-hide-small w3-right w3-hover-red">
        <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Navbar on small screens -->
    <div id="navDemo" class="w3-bar-block w3-white w3-hide w3-hide-large w3-hide-medium">
      <a href="#about" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="toggleFunction()">ABOUT</a>
      <a href="#portfolio" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="toggleFunction()">PORTFOLIO</a>
      <a href="#contact" class="w3-bar-item w3-button" onclick="toggleFunction()">CONTACT</a>
      <a href="#" class="w3-bar-item w3-button">SEARCH</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- First Parallax Image with Logo Text -->
  <div class="bgimg-1 w3-display-container w3-opacity-min" id="home">
    <div class="w3-display-middle" style="white-space:nowrap;">
      <span class="w3-center w3-padding-large w3-black w3-xlarge w3-wide w3-animate-opacity">MY <span class="w3-hide-small">WEBSITE</span> LOGO</span>

    </div>
  </div>
```